# Xamarin Forms - populate a custom control when page opens

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

The following is a custom control in a XAML page to show images in a slider control (I wont include the C# code for the control it's self unless asked to)

```
    <custom:ImageGallery ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" Grid.Row="1">
                    <custom:ImageGallery.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Aspect="AspectFit" >
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.PreviewImageCommand, Source={x:Reference ThePage}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ImageId}" />
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </custom:ImageGallery.ItemTemplate>
                </custom:ImageGallery>
<Button
                Grid.Row="2"
                Text="populate"
                Command="{Binding PopulateCommand}">
            </Button>
```

At the moment the control is populated when the button is clicked.
Here is the command the button is bound to:

```
public ObservableCollection<GalleryImage> Images
{
    get
    {
       return _images;
    }
}

public ICommand PopulateCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () => await PopulateImagesCommand(), () => true);
    }
}

public async Task PopulateImagesCommand()
{
          // adds images to the observable collection 'Images'
}
```

Rather than populate on click of a button I'd rather do it as soon as the page opens.  I had tried changing

```
public ObservableCollection<GalleryImage> Images
{
    get
    {
         return _images;
    }
}
```

to

```
public ObservableCollection<GalleryImage> Images
{
    get
    {
       PopulateImagesCommand();
       return _images;
    }
}
```

But that does not work obviously.
Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it when the page with the control first appears:

```
private bool hasAlreadyAppeared;
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    if(!hasAlreadyAppeared) {
        hasAlreadyAppeared = true;
        MyImageGallery.Populate();
    }
}
```

Of course, you would have to expose the `Populate` method, and inside of it you would execute the `PopulateCommand`.

Comment: I can see what you're doing there and when debugging the ItemSource gets populated within the override of OnAppearing, but it still doesn't update in the page, I'll need to look further into this

Comment: You're saying that your `Images` ObservableCollection gets populated, but the results are not shown? Then I think you have a problem somewhere else. I always do things like this in the `OnAppearing` when the page first appears, so this definitely should work.